# One-sided variant of Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

For random variable $X$ with standard deviation $\sigma$, and any $t>0$, show that $$\Pr(X-E[X]\geq t\sigma)\leq\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}.$$

[Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) yields  $$\Pr(|X-E[X]|\geq t\sigma)\leq\dfrac{1}{t^2},$$ so we also have $$\Pr(X-E[X]\geq t\sigma)\leq\dfrac{1}{t^2}.$$ but how can we get $\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Cantelli inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality), which states that $$P(X-E[X]\ge a)\le\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$ Taking $a=t\sigma$ yields directly the one-sided Chebyshev inequality, since $$P(X-E[X]\ge t\sigma)\le\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+t^2\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$$

---

(but I am not sure if that is what you wanted, or if you wanted also a proof of the Cantelli inequality).

Comment: do you have a source for the proof?

Comment: @mookid you can find in the references of the wikipedia link

Comment: nice (+1). The link to the proof is http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2011/Spring-694/lectures/l4.pdf at the end of p.1